# Mongod starting error (errno 45) : Unable to lock file

Tags: mongodb, database

When I try to start mongod with the following command:

```
mongod --dbpath data/db
```

I get the following error:

```
    [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: 
data/db/mongod.lock errno:45 Operation not supported. Is a mongod instance 
already running?, terminating
```

but when I use the `ps` command line, I don't see any running mongod instance.

I have tried to:

- delete the whole directory `data/` and recreate the path `data/db`
- change the rights of the file `mongod.lock`

But none of these worked.

Any idea of what I should do? Thanks

Comment: If you are sure it's not running you can remove the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not All File systems support locking, Are you by any chance using NFS?
could you add FS type, mount options and permissions for your data folder?

Comment: Yes I am using NFS but I can't change the configuration where I am.
Thank you for your answer, at least I know where the problem comes from.